# How to make VSCode Intellisense window wider

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have a VSCode extension that helps me autocomplete file paths, however many file paths grow long and are truncated in the VSCode intellisense popover window.

How can I set VSCode to either:

- have a fixed width that I can set to be large
- automatically expand to fit the intellisense options (preferable)

I happen to have written the extension so if needed I can update it if that is required.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/64492059/836330 this functionality has been added to the Insiders' Build v1.51.

Comment: It appears to be a fixed width only - not dynamic.  Also works for the details box on the right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think this is possible, VSCode generally gives extensions very little control over the built-in UI. See also the [*Restrictions*](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-capabilities/overview#no-dom-access) section of the *Extensions Capabilities Overview*. Technically there is [a way to hack around that](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=be5invis.vscode-custom-css), but I wouldn't necessarily recommend it.

There are also a number of settings for the suggest widget, but none of them seems to correspond directly to width. The closest you can get would be reducing the font size with `"editor.suggestFontSize"`.

Comment: Bummer that the actual question can't be addressed, but using `"editor.suggestFontSize"` in this case seems like a good solution. What I want is a way to make the "read more" box (with the details of the underlying function) wider and/or have smaller text, and there's currently no way to do that AFAICT.

Comment: this really sucks my files have very long names which often start with the same thing and do not fit within this small window =(

Answer (score 13):

You can resize suggestion window with mouse.

Comment: Hah, didn't realize it would be this easy. It would be nice to have a drag handle on the end of it to make it more obvious.

Comment: This is the answer, after resizing with the mouse the new width persists next invocation of the menu.

Comment: After 8 years of using VSCode... I just learned something new.

Answer (score 10):

One way around this is to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> (or what ever your "Trigger suggestion" shortcut is) while the suggestion popover is open to show more detail about current selection.

So this (where I can't differentiate between the `Trans` imported from `@lingui/macro` and the one from `@lingui/react`):

[image: small suggestion popup]

Becomes this:

[image: larger suggestion popup]