# need to move intellisense popup window in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, mql4

I want to move the intellisense popup window to the left side.

How can I do this?

I tried this solution but it did not help me.

[How to make VSCode Intellisense window wider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57010536/how-to-make-vscode-intellisense-window-wider)

[image]

Comment: This is going to be really hard to accomplish, natively. There are extensions where you could include your own css. The real issue is you don't have insight on where the 'left most' position of the word boundary is. Meaning, if you want it to left align with the word 'for', how do you know where that word is (In terms of styling)? As it stands now never say never, but I'm almost certain this would require an extension / manual intervention. You can see if this helps https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=be5invis.vscode-custom-css

Answer (score 1):

#### change width

For adjusting the width, you can drag the right side of the window now, see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64491930/is-there-a-way-to-resize-the-autocomplete-widget-in-visual-studio-code/64492059#64492059) for an old animation.

On mac the right of the popup will turn blue when hovered (cursor isn't captured in screenshot) and can be resized. You can also resize vertically by hovering the bottom. It looks like this on mac (not sure about other OS):

[image]

#### change position

The new version (October 2021 (version 1.62)) makes it easy to move the position... sort of. You can now choose to have the editor above or below what you hover. So glad they added it as a feature. This wasn't exactly the problem you had, but when I first searched for moving the intellisense menu, it led me here, so figured I'd add this for others Google sends here.

Simply add the following to `settings.json` file:

```json
"editor.hover.above": false
```

Add a comma after it if you have more settings below it:

```json
"editor.hover.above": false,
"editor.minimap.enabled": false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to configure intellisense within VScode using the steps in https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_customizing-intellisense, though I am not sure if your particular issue could be solved this way.