# Is there a way to resize the autocomplete widget in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can't seem to be able to resize the autocomplete widget in Visual Studio Code, I would like to make the documentation window wider, the one that appears when the user presses ctrl-space with the cursor inside a word. Is it possible to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is actually in the Insiders Build now for v1.51.  You can just drag the right side longer and the new size will be remembered.

[image: expand suggestion box demo]

Comment: given that this is in the Insiders Build, this means that this feature will eventually come to the Stable version, right?

Comment: Yes, almost always in the next Stable build, so should be early November 2020.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/64492157/836330 for a little more info.